# Vertical line spacing in Visual Studio Code's embedded terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

I've set up Powerlevel10k on ZSH for WSL2 on VSCode, and have gone through the normal configuration procedures, such that the terminal prompt currently looks like this:

[image]

However, if possible I would like to increase the vertical line spacing between the first and second line of the prompt to avoid having the cursor touch the coloured segments. Is there a way to do this? Or if possible can I decrease the size of the cursor?

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio code:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to open Settings.
2. Type `integrated line height`.
3. Change the value to something larger than `1`, for example, `1.4`.

Comment: It only stretches the height of each line, it doesn't affect the vertical spacing between each line.